# Prove that the function $F(f)=\int_a^bf(x)dx$ is continuous.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

Define $d:X\times X\to \mathbb{R}$ by 
$$d(f,g)=\int_a^b |f(x)-g(x)|dx$$
Let $\rho$ be the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that the function $F:X\to\mathbb{R}$ defined $$F(f)=\int_a^bf(x)dx$$ is continuous.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|F(f)-F(g)|=\left| \int_a^b f(x)dx - \int_a^b g(x)dx\right|=\left| \int_a^b (f(x)-g(x))dx \right| \le \int_a^b |f(x)-g(x)|dx = d(f,g)$$

which shows that $F$ is a contraction: we can take $\delta=\epsilon$ uniformly.

So $F: C([a,b]) \to \mathbb{R}$ is (uniformly) continuous.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that $f$ and $g$ are continuous, we have
$$ \rho(F(f),F(g))=|F(f-g)|\leqslant d(f,g) $$
so that $F$ is continuous.